# Windows phone 8.1 universal app Image touch behaviour

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, touch, win-universal-app

I have a grid with images and textblocks, this is the xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContainerView" Background="Transparent">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="4">
        <Image Source="ms-appx:/Images/background_azure.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Grid>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Gridway Mobile Lab" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="25" ></TextBlock>
    <Rectangle 
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
           Tapped="ToSampling"
        />

    <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
           Margin="40,20,40,50"
           Source="ms-appx:/Images/prelievi.png" 
           Stretch="Fill"
           Tapped="ToSampling"
           />

    <TextBlock 
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
        Margin="10,10,10,10"
        Text="Lista Prelievi"      
        FontSize="30"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        />

    <Rectangle
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
           Tapped="ToSetting"
            Margin="10,10,10,10"/>

    <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
           Margin="45,25,45,50"
           Source="ms-appx:/Images/settings.png" 
           Stretch="Fill"
           Tapped="ToSetting"
           />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="10,10,10,10"
        Text="Impostazioni"      
        FontSize="30"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        />

    <Rectangle 
        Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" 
           Tapped="ToSync"
        Margin="10,10,10,10"/>

    <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" 
           Margin="40,10,40,50"
           Tapped="ToSync"
           Source="ms-appx:/Images/sync.png" 
           Stretch="Fill"
           />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" 
        Margin="10,10,10,10"
        Text="Sincronizza"      
        FontSize="30"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        />

    <Rectangle 
        Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
           Tapped="ToMessages"
        Margin="10,10,10,10"/>

    <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
           Margin="40,10,40,50"
           Tapped="ToMessages"
           Source="ms-appx:/Images/message.png" 
           Stretch="Fill"
           />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
        Margin="10,10,10,10"
        Text="Avvisi"      
        FontSize="30"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        />

    <Rectangle 
        Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
           Tapped="ToTimbs"
        Margin="10,10,10,10"/>

    <Image Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
           Tapped="ToTimbs"
           Margin="25,20,25,20"
           Source="ms-appx:/Images/timbratura.png" 
           Stretch="Fill"
           />

    <TextBlock 
         Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
           Margin="10,10,10,10"
        Text="Timbrature"      
        FontSize="30"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        />

</Grid>
```

My problem is simple, I want my images to have the same behaviour of a button when the user touches them. They simply have to "move back" and then come forward again exactly as the animation of touching a simple button.

It is ok even if only the image is moving like that, but I don't really know how to achieve this, any help will be really appreciate.

Thanks all and sorry for my bad english, if you need some more infos tell me

Comment: What you can do is wrap the image in a border. Listen to the pointerPressed events and set the margin to 10. Note that you can also set the background of a Button.